# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource on spring app

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

Whenever I launch my application, I have this issue from spring web context listener.
This is the complete stacktrace of the exception

**First stacktrace**

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;
```

on the second line of the exception I get this second stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlReaderContext.getEnvironment()Lorg/springframework/core/env/Environment;
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:81)
```

this is the content of my spring-servlet.xml file

```
<!-- Configuration defining views files -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
        <value>/jsp/</value>
            <!-- <value>/</value> -->
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
<!--     <tx:annotation-driven /> -->
<!--      <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager"></bean>  -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/js/**" location="/resources/js/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/css/**" location="/resources/css/" />
<!-- <aop:config>  
  <aop:aspect id="myaspect" ref="checkLogin1" >  
       @Before    
     <aop:pointcut id="pointCutBefore"   expression="execution(* cntrlr.cntrlrUser..*(..))" />  
     <aop:before method="myadvice" pointcut-ref="pointCutBefore" />  
  </aop:aspect>  
</aop:config> -->  

<mvc:interceptors>
<mvc:interceptor>
<mvc:mapping path="/jsp/user/**"/> 
<bean class="interceptor.CheckLogin" />
</mvc:interceptor>

</mvc:interceptors>

<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

My tomcat is refusing to launching my application. Please what could be wrong?

Comment: could you please share the entire configuration..I suspect some thing has duplicate entry

Comment: You are mixing different versions of spring jars.

Comment: dont get you please. where is it happening

Comment: Could you show us your pom.xml if you have one? Or whatever else you are using to manage your build?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
```